# Display active category, sub category after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to display active category after page reload
first I tried by using URL and PHP
but its not work on sub category
now I'm trying to achieve this by using JavaScript or jQuery.
Below is my PHP code

```
function multilevel($connection, $parent = 0, $cat_id)
{

    $side = '';
    $sql = '';
    if ($parent == 0) {
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `categorys` WHERE parent_id = 0 ANd  cats_status = 1 ORDER BY cats_name ASC";
    } else {
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `categorys` WHERE parent_id = $parent ANd  cats_status = 1 ORDER BY cats_name ASC";
    }

    $result =  mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    // $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == 0) {
            $side .= "<li class='categorys'>
                        <h3>
                            <a href='?cat_id=" . $row['cats_id'] . "' id='" . $row['cats_id'] . "' class='nav-link'>" . $row['cats_name'] . "</a>
                        </h3>";
        } else {
            $side .= "<li class='categorys'>
                        <h3>
                            <a href='?cat_id=" . $row['cats_id'] . "' id='" . $row['cats_id'] . "' class='nav-link'>" . $row['cats_name'] . "</a>
                        </h3>";
        }

        $side .= "<ul class='nav nav-link collapse' id='submenu'>" . multilevel($connection, $row['cats_id'], $row['cats_id']) . "</ul>";
        $side .= "</li>";
    }

    return $side;
}
$cat_id = get_save_data($connection, $_GET['cat_id']);
echo multilevel($connection, 0, $cat_id);
```

here is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordian a").click(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var closest_ul = link.closest("ul");
        var parallel_active_links = closest_ul.find(".active")
        var closest_li = link.closest("li");
        var link_status = closest_li.hasClass("active");
        var count = 0;

        closest_ul.find("ul").slideUp(function() {
            if (++count == closest_ul.find("ul").length)
                parallel_active_links.removeClass("active");
        });

        if (!link_status) {
            closest_li.children("ul").slideDown();
            closest_li.addClass("active");
        }
    })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-item a").on("click", function() {
        $(".nav-item.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }).filter(function() {
        return window.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href').trim()) > -1;
    }).click();
});
```

by using PHP I'm unable to show sub category active, that's why I'm trying to achieve this by jQuery.
Is there any way to show active category using URL parameter or maybe without URL

Comment: When using PHP you can use the session to store it, then display it if it is set on refresh

Comment: @brombeer 
i tried using session its only work for main category but when i click on any sub category 
its not work

Comment: I don't see why that shouldn't work unless you did something wrong. If it works for the main category it should also work for a sub category.

Comment: is this because of i didnt comment javascript code. so may be js code forcefully lapse subcategory?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: how do i get query parameters present in the url, you can use $_GET superglobal variable. it's an array that you can inspect (more info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php ).

Please note that your users can put any string in the url (so it's not safe to run database queries based on what your users where typing there.. but ok, i suppose it's safe in your situation, where you just need to make a comparison)

Comment: sorry but you misunderstood my question
i want to show active category or sub category by using url parameter. Whenever user click on any category that category id send to url, to fetch data related to that
but after page reload thats side bar category list not expand